# Make fails to notice changes

Tags: makefile

I have an issue with Make failing to rebuild a target because it doesn't believe that anything has changed. I've distilled the issue down to the following two Makefiles:

1) Makefile

```
.DEFAULT_GOAL := all

%:
    @echo "Catch all for $@"
    @make -sf common.mk $@
```

2) common.mk

```
.PHONY: all clean

all:
    @make -s package
    @echo "Nothing to do for all"

package: ${shell find ./src -type f}
    @echo "The following files have changed... $?"
    @echo "Making 'package'"
    @touch package

clean:
    @echo "Cleaning 'package'"
    @rm -f package
```

With the above, you can reproduce the issue by:

```
$mkdir src
$touch src/test.c
$make
```

At this point, if you try and make again, it correctly determines that nothing has changed...

```
$make
```

But then, if you simulate a change and try to rebuild, it doesn't think anything has changed...

```
$touch src/test.c
$make
```

If I move the 'package' target from common.mk to Makefile, it works fine, so there is something it really doesn't like, but I'm really not sure what is going on.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you think anything in the top-level Makefile should trigger the `%` pattern rule and pull in your `common.mk`? Putting the real meat in a separate file is the fundamental problem here, though if your real-world code is much more complex, there could be a reason to do that. What *actual* problem are you trying to solve with this arrangement?

Comment: Routinely masking all your commands with `@` is an antipattern. Use `make -s` if you don't want to see Make's output; but don't make it impossible to debug your recipes.

Comment: Having Make print "nothing to do for all" when in fact it did something seems misdirected as well.

Comment: The curlies around `shell` are a syntax error; you want round parentheses, not curly braces. It's a silent error, though; perhaps this is the real problem you are chasing?

Comment: Thanks for your comments so far. Yes, this is a distillation of a much larger and more complex set of files -- it's a minimal reproduction case.

Comment: Ha! I think you might be right about the curlies, in place of parentheses enclosing the shell find. I can't test it right now, though.

Comment: With GNU Make, you shoud probably just `include common.mk`

Comment: Using curly braces around make functions is just fine, same as using them around make variables.  Either works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
all:
    @make -s package
```

In that call to Make, you don't specify which makefile to use, so Make *looks for the defaults and finds a file named "Makefile".* The new instance of Make attempts to rebuild `package` using the makefile `Makefile`, and finds this rule:

```
%:
    @echo "Catch all for $@"
    @make -sf common.mk $@
```

Note that this rule has no prerequisites, `package` has not been declared `PHONY`, and a file named "package" already exists. So Make[1] sees no reason to rebuild the file, and terminates, passing control back to its parent Make.